# Backplate for satin nickel deadlock

Tags: doors, lock, deadbolt

There is an old door with some marks from a jimmyproof lock. It was replaced with a single cylinder deadlock, satin nickel finish.
To cover the marks, it was decided to install a back plate covering the affected area (a rectangle of 4 x 6). Of course this back plate will have a hole so the deadlock goes through it.

What materials do you suggest to cut to this size that will blend well with the satin nickel?
Initially I thought about opaque acrylic but it might not look good (plastic looking versus metal deadlock). Maybe a metal looking acrylic that I found, or an aluminum sheet? How difficult would it be to cut the hole on them?

PS: it is inside a safe building, it does not requires strong protection. It is more for the looks (cover imperfections from the jimmyproof lock that was removed) than for security. Painting is not an option because the door got damaged in this area and it was decided to not replace the door.

Appreciate any ideas for materials that would go well with the new satin nickel deadlock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of places online that do custom metal work. They do anything you want, you just have to explain with proper dimensions or send a vector file. For example, brushed stainless steel rectangle with a hole in the middle (my need). They even do round edges.

I went that way. The result will look like part of the original deadlock.

Not totally DIY, but in this case the look was more important so having a proper place do this custom piece was the best thing to do. For curiosity, a 6.5 in x 3.75 in stainless steel rectangle, 1/16 thick, round edges, with a 2 1/8 centered hole (standard deadlock cut) cost $47 with tax and shipping (March 2020). It will be ready to install when delivered, in the exact dimensions I need.

Thanks for all the ideas!

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to match the color of the satin nickel hardware as good as possible, I would recommend cutting it from... Satin Nickel.  The same companies that make door locks also make "kick plates" for the bottom of the door, and smaller "push plates" that are made to push open a door that doesn't have a knob (normally seen in commercial doors).  Here is an [example](https://www.homedepot.com/p/National-Hardware-3-1-2-in-x-15-in-Satin-Nickel-Pull-Plate-N207-878/203951143) of a push plate.  You could use one of these like a piece of sheet metal to cut whatever size and shape you wanted.

They also sell door reenforcement plates that are used to cover up damage:

[image]

[Example here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-1-3-4-in-x-9-in-Thick-Solid-Brass-Lock-and-Door-Reinforcer-2-1-8-in-Single-Bore-2-3-8-in-Backset-U-9586/100285175)

Most home stores will have these in stock - I randomly picked Home Depot to link to, but these are common items if you know what to look for.

Comment: Thank you, but my sizes are different. These comes with holes already and all that I looked are incompatible with what I need. It seems that buying a plain metal sheet and cutting it to my size is still the best.

Comment: @igorjrr, right, a nickel door kick is a good choice then.  It's a pretty large sheet of metal that you can do whatever you want with.

Comment: Yes, they are big... trying to find something smaller to avoid waste or cheaper. Are they easy to cut at home? What tool would you recommend? I have a rotary tool with metal cutting wheels.

Comment: @igorjrr, they are pretty thin so you can cut them with about anything made for metal.  The trick is going to be getting a nice, smooth cut without the proper (large) metal cutting machines.  A dremel will work, but the edge will need to be sanded smooth with various grits to get a smooth , straight edge.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a lot of choices because you need to have the piece thin. Even plastic might be too thick.

Wood would look very good I believe, and can be as thin as veneer. Put a nice veneer on a sheet of metal backing. And, with veneer, you have lots of options for the wood species, including many exotics and others. You can get veneer with a sticky backing already applied so it's as simple to apply as a vinyl sticker. Pick a nice color or pattern to match the metal and anything else near the door.

[image]
[image]
[image]